# Count number of equal columns in the same week of several years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains 1 column named Week and 5 columns named n1, n2, n3, n4 and n5.
I wanted to count how many of the n1, n2... n5 columns match for each week.

So far I created a query that shows all n1...n5 ordered by week

```
select e.Week, e.Year, e.n1, e.n2, e.n3, e.n4, e.n5, e.Date
from Entries e
order by e.Week asc, e.Year asc
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Enties](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Week] [int] NULL,
    [n1] [int] NULL,
    [n2] [int] NULL,
    [n3] [int] NULL,
    [n4] [int] NULL,
    [n5] [int] NULL,
    [sup] [int] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Enties] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I used SQL Server but this is a general sql question.
Any ideas how can I achieve this?

UPDATE:
let's say that the table contains 3 yeas and so 3 equal weeks for each year.
I wanted to know how many of the

```
week1.n1=week2.n1=week3.n1, week1.n2=week2.n2=week3.n2, ...
```

are equal in each week.

The result will be something like

```
Week1 = 0 match,
Week2 = 2 match,
Week3 = 1 matches,
...
```

Comment: Do you want all n1 to n5 columns to match ?

Comment: If `n1` matches `n2`, and `n3` matches `n4`, does this count as one match, or two matches?

Comment: The table definition and the query shown do not match. Different names, columns missing in the table create that are used in the query.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want for output?  For instance, if they all match, do you want "5" because they all match?  10 because of the number of pairwise matches?  1 because there is only one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use Boolean expressions for their numerical values if you wrap then in a `CASE` expression.

You could count the number of simultaneous matches like this:

```
select
    (Round/2) as Week
,   e.Year
,   SUM(
        (case when n1=n2 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n1=n3 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n1=n4 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n1=n5 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n2=n3 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n2=n4 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n2=n5 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n3=n4 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n3=n5 then 1 else 0 end)
    +   (case when n4=n5 then 1 else 0 end)
    ) as MatchCount
from Entries
group by (Round/2), Year
order by Round asc, Year asc
```

The argument of `SUM` lists all pairs of {n<sub>i</sub>, n<sub>j</sub>} from your table, counting the number of pairwise matches.

Comment: @Bonomi I edited the answer to match SQL Server syntax.